# nodejs app won't deploy in heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, drywall

My app works when I do foreman start, but it won't work on Heroku. I noticed that I was getting an error with the ./config file mainly because it was in the gitignore and not being deployed, so just for TESTING reasons, I removed it from gitignore and tried to see if that would fix it. But it still does not seem to be working. Can anyone help me out? Here are my heroku logs:

(Also I am using drywall)

```
2014-08-12T17:14:07.323424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=e32e4293-4910-45c1-9a3a-c76903476258 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:13:58+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-12T17:13:58.149660+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a4cdf51 by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:13:58.149752+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:14:02.366525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-12T17:14:00.204911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `grunt`
2014-08-12T17:14:02.335971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-08-12T17:14:05.660037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=521a956c-3e6e-4d49-bec5-0f28194a60c5 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:20:44.295250+00:00 heroku[api]: Set NODE_ENV config vars by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:20:44.295250+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:20:57.068495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-08-12T17:20:54.863151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2014-08-12T17:19:16.354869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-12T17:19:08+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-12T17:19:15.700596+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2b7c46e by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:19:15.700658+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:19:19.377902+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T17:19:19.378418+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-12T17:19:19.378634+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-12T17:19:19.378641+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-12T17:19:19.381796+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './config'
2014-08-12T17:19:19.381799+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-12T17:19:19.381801+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-12T17:19:19.381802+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-12T17:19:19.381804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-12T17:19:19.381806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:4:14)
2014-08-12T17:19:19.381807+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-12T17:19:24.243885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=914a4430-7738-40fc-a2b7-d3dbdc6f7729 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:19:20.524608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-08-12T17:19:25.056809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=8777e752-fa64-4d9d-993f-c01851cce162 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:19:26.424936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=f5bed113-a89c-4f9c-987f-5c5282d0157f fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:23:47.079989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-12T17:23:56.492672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=9f209d37-0689-4308-abbb-aed18a68b175 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:20:52.036021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-12T17:20:53.178222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-12T17:20:47.869755+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-12T17:20:44.633384+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-12T17:20:51.296381+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T17:20:51.297136+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-12T17:20:51.297142+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300238+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './config'
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300241+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300242+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300243+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300246+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:4:14)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300249+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300250+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300252+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-12T17:20:51.300255+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-08-12T17:20:50.585304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2014-08-12T17:20:52.026562+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-08-12T17:20:55.727483+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T17:20:55.728534+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-12T17:20:55.728547+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732018+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './config'
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732021+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732023+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732024+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732026+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732028+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:4:14)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732030+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732031+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732033+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732034+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-12T17:20:55.732036+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-08-12T17:20:57.078969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-12T17:20:52.415440+00:00 heroku[api]: Set NODE_PATH config vars by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:20:52.415489+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by thomas@gmail.com
2014-08-12T17:21:11.492538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=e7a76b2b-dc1f-40e4-b7bd-0c1a0ac1edfd fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:23:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-12T17:23:51.714867+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 17:23:51 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at node_modules/body-parser/index.js:75:29
2014-08-12T17:23:51.733428+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 17:23:51 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at app.js:46:9
2014-08-12T17:23:52.132788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-12T17:23:53.656306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T17:23:53.656379+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:178
2014-08-12T17:23:53.656728+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw err;
2014-08-12T17:23:53.656735+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658395+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658398+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:553:74)
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658399+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:106:17)
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658401+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658403+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:98:17)
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658404+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:512:10)
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658406+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658408+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:440:14
2014-08-12T17:23:53.658409+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
2014-08-12T17:23:56.192869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=8216e058-bc56-46ab-a80e-aea67fabffda fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:23:54.916347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2014-08-12T17:23:57.346040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=e111aee2-6e6e-44db-9473-7f2a628f63ec fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:23:57.653972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=96887a45-6892-4f62-8359-93b1e399b800 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:23:54.904810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-08-12T17:24:15.758626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=ea6d2dda-a9f8-4ba3-b5af-b01e0376f0a0 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:24:16.067375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=c6d02962-8fb2-4e27-af59-bc223309f054 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:24:19.674990+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-12T17:24:27.266230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-12T17:24:30.244678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2014-08-12T17:24:34.058914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=d4f12ec9-8716-4f3c-930d-746dc785e6ba fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno=web.1 connect=5001ms service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:28:32.844457+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=58b7d7fa-773f-4c31-8d78-59286c0998e4 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-12T17:28:33.379276+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-stream-8969.herokuapp.com request_id=6e739939-ddac-49e4-8d67-3c9578c54482 fwd="98.77.179.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to remove the config file from gitignore. You need to add config.js to the repository. After removing it from gitignore, commit that file, push changes, and run the deployment again.

Comment: still no luck, I'm getting this error 
2014-08-12T18:18:31.894146+00:00 app[web.1]: mongoose connection error:  [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
2014-08-12T18:18:32.307870+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-12T18:18:29.065566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2014-08-12T18:19:06.465350+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T18:19:06.467307+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]

Comment: Ok, it's a different error. Make sure MongoDB connection details are correct.

Comment: you're correct. Here's the code in my config: exports.mongodb = {
  uri: process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 'localhost/drywall'
};. If none of the process variable's are set, it defaults to localhost/drywall. Any idea how I can set one of these process variables through heroku?

Comment: `MONGOLAB_URI` and `MONGOHQ_URL` are environment variable. Here is an article how you can set environment variables: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars You can also just search for "set environment variable on heroku".

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out a newbie! You've made my day so much easier. Got it working like a charm :)

Comment: Good to hear that! :)